# firebase provide facility to upload json in other languages apart from english

Tags: firebase

Does fire base support internationalization, like supporting other languages other than English. 
I need to upload a json which contains fonts in other languages like German ,France ,etc..

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything on Firebase's support page. I really think you should be able to use multiple languages since it just stores text.

I was able to find an article where someone did create an internationalization application using firebase. It stored the localized strings.

http://hwclass.in/developing-javascript-applications-supporting-simple-i18n/

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments